# how to get the state for outgoing calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In the `OnReceive` method  I have something like this:

```
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
   String phonenumber=intent.getStrngExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

How to chech if the dialing call is still on or the client hanged up the call?
How to check if the call was answered?

I need to print up a toat when the client hanged up the call or when the called client answered to the call.

Comment: this link                                            http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-read-precise-state-of-outgoing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below code for handling call state:::

```
    private Runnable callMonitor = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
                TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)m_activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("callMonitor", "Exception: "+e.toString());
            }
        }
    };   

    private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        private boolean active = false;
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                Log.i("EndCallListener", "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            }
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
                active = true;
                Log.i("EndCallListener", "OFFHOOK");
            }
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
                Log.i("EndCallListener", "IDLE");
                if (active) {
                    active = false;

                    // stop listening                   
                    TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)m_activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    mTM.listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

                    // restart the inbox activity
//                  Intent intent = new Intent(m_activity, MDInboxActivity.class);
//                  m_activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is state defined means?

Comment: just paste this two functions in your activity and before calling any number

Comment: how to check if the outgoing call is canceled?

Comment: CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK is called immediately upon dialing. There is no state that you can use to determine if the receiver has picked up the phone.

Comment: This is not the answer. It does not work for knowing when the outgoing was answered. Only when it started ringing on the other side.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a broadcast receiver registered for action **android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE**

iF THE phone state has **not** changed to *idle* once it is *offhook*, it means the call is still going on.

the call was **answered** if the state in read phone state broadcast receiver **changes to offhook**.  Put a toast as need in these states.

```
   public class CallDurationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static boolean flag =false;
static long start_time,end_time;    
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

               //tOAST FOR INCOMING CALL, NOT YET PICKED UP

            }         
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                end_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
 //Total time talked =
                long total_time = end_time-start_time;
                //Store total_time somewhere or pass it to an Activity using intent

}     if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                 start_time=System.currentTimeMillis();

}    

    }   
    }
```

Register your receiver in your manifest file like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallDurationReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        }
```

Also add the uses permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I need to detect when the outgoing call is canceled or hanged-up. how to check that?

Comment: you can't differentiate between an outgoing/incoming call AFAIK.I gave you the code above to do that. When the state is IDLE, the call is done.so, put all your code in IDLE state if condition.

Answer (score 2):

Well all I find out a solution for this and I successfully implemented it.Its not possible to fetch the exact time when the callee has accepted an outgoing call.

Before picking up a call in the other end it has already passed through 2 stages namely `on_State_idle` and `on_state_offhook`. `On_state_ringing` is not working for the outgoing calls.

Let's assume a phone is ringing for 40sec (this am not sure) continuously if the person at the other side didn't pick the call.

1. Start a timer along with the starting stage of `on_State_idle` and `on_state_offhook`.
2. Two cases if the timer cross above 40sec means the person at the other hand pick my call.
3. If `on_State_idle->on_state_offhook->on_State_idle` worked within 40sec means the other hand didn't pick my call.
4. If the second case is true, fetch the call talk duration from the call log.
5. Totaltimer running time - time in call log gives you the exact time of picking of the outgoing Call!

Comment: visit this link http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-read-precise-state-of-outgoing.html

Comment: how about getting call duration when you are doing call using sip endpoint to mobile enpoint ? here the call logs doesn't have call duration.