# How to detect TelephonyManager outgoing call connected State on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

We have **`3 States`** according to this **documentation** [Fields](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager?hl=en#fields_1)

The below code shows Ringing State how we can detect via **`TelephonyManager`** outgoing call connected State on Android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
   }

   public class myPhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {
       @Override
       public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
           super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
           if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
               String phoneNumber =   incomingNumber;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance. if you need anything from me please ask in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It's very easy just add the code below inside your **`myPhoneStateChangeListener`**'s **`onCallStateChanged`** method

```
if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK==state) {
    // phone picked up
}
if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE==state) {
    // either phone hanged up or ringing stopped
}
```

or you can refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213843/16177121)

Alternatively, You can also use [BroadcastReciever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) to check the state change.

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        assert bundle != null;
        String phoneState = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.d("phoneCallReceiver", phoneState);

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.d("phoneCallReceiver", "phone hanged up");
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            Log.d("phoneCallReceiver", "phone picked up");
        }
        if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Log.d("phoneCallReceiver", "phone ringing");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for this answer, but I need a connected state when a call is connected and the timer starts on phone

Comment: EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK is not the state where call is picked up i tried

Comment: @RobinHood try filtering the action inside `BrodcastReciever` using `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())`

Comment: ok i'll try this also

Comment: @RobinHood If filtering action doesn't resolve your problem refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee)

Comment: this one i already using

Comment: @RobinHood there is no state for *call picked*, You have to *track* the state changed which can be done by the `BroadcastReciever` or `PhoneStateListener`

Comment: then how the `Twilio` provides you a connected state.

Comment: @RobinHood Yes, Twilio API provides connected states it also establishes connections. So if establishes connections it knows whether the connection is established or not.  _And I said there is no state for call picked provided by android itself_